# Zoom Levels GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have some very high resolution imagery that I want to display through Geoserver but it keeps shutting off the image if I zoom in too far.  I have tried all the settings in the Tile Caching tab with regard to zoom levels on a gridset but I have not been able to solve the problem.  I don't want any restrictions on zoom/display but can't seem to get there!

Comment: Geoserver has no concept of zoom level. Please provide more details of the client you are using and what errors you get and what is in the log file.

Comment: I was feeding the kml of an image WMS from Geoserver to both QGIS and Google Earth.  You can zoom in to a certain point and then the image just disappears.  No errors logged or otherwise, just gone.  The same response in both QGIS and Google Earth.  Vectors served up this way work just fine. Would have something to do with compression inside method of the GeoTiff itself?  (Nice to have the geoserver man himself to ask!)

Comment: No idea, really. What does the log file say? what does the KML say? are you using the reflector or a full WMS string? what urls are sent, what is in the response returned? please use the [edit] button to improve your question